# How to keep REST API session in Python code alive?

Tags: python, apache, rest, api

I am trying to write a code on Python which will allow me to send REST API requests to server by using bearer token as Authentication. How an I do that?

Basically, what I am trying to achieve:
Imagine you have a server which creates some projects and you can set different parameters for this project. 
Server is running on Apache and I want to write a script on Python which will allow me to work with requests.

```
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (
            'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'sp',
        ),
    ),
}
```

I tried to implement this code which I also found on stackoveflow (Btw I am lost what does 'sp' mean).And it doesn't work - next requests comes with 403.

I do understand that I am missing some fundamental coding knowledge and would really appreciate if anyone can advise on decent course with REST API.

Comment: Hi Riley, if you're looking to build a restful API i would  suggest learning a bit of Flask. It's not going to be all essential but it provides a really nice microframework for developing REST APIs. I would very much suggest the [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) to get to terms with it. Then you can move on to [this api tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask)

Comment: I wish I could some-how like your message.

Here is an update in regards of my task:

```import requests

auth_token='sometokenhash'
hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token}
raw_data = 'nameofProject'

url = ' urltoserver'
response = requests.post(url, data=raw_data, headers=hed)
print(response)

```

And for some reason I get 403 error. When I run GET request via postman - I get request OK, but post doesn't work as well.